# Adding Comments to R Code in Sweave

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am working on a document about R software, which is currently stored in a Rnw file to eventually process it with Sweave. The document contains several R code chunks, of the usual form:

```
<<>>= 
R Code
@
```

Next to some code lines, I would like to add specific comments, which I would like to be displayed like usual LaTeX text (so that they are easily recognizable as comments). Is there a way to display R code chunks and corresponding comments next to each other when using sweave or knitR?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "next to each other". Do you want a small section of page in two columns, with R code in one column and LaTeX next to it?

Comment: Also, I think you should not call these "comments". Comments are what you would add in the R code with the `#` comment character. It sounds like you *don't* want comments, you want standard LaTeX (the content of which may or may not be to comment on the R code as you wish).

Comment: That said, if your main concern is *"so that they are easily recognizable as comments"*, you should just use regular R comments in your code chunk and let syntax highlighting change the color so that they stand out. [You can do it this way with Sweave](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5113/10371), or it will be done by default if you switch to `knitr`.

Comment: @Llarian, does my answer help, or did I miss something?

Comment: @ Gregor: Yes, I would like two different columns, it that is possible. The left columns should contain R code which is easily recognizable as such. The right column should present remarks to specific code lines, which are formatted like the main text. If that cannot be done, I could choose the solution via knitr that you pointed out; thanks for that.

Comment: In that case the answer is all LaTeX. Basically you want to switch from a single column layout to a two column layout for code and commentary, then switch back again, all on the same page. LaTeX doesn't care if what you put in the left column is an R code chunk, regular LaTeX, an image, a tabular environment, or anything else. I suggest you look for a pure LaTeX solution, maybe [like this](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Multiple_columns).

Comment: @Gregor: After following your hint, I also encountered minipages, which allow a similar solution by putting R chunks in one column and my remarks in a second one. I will try out all suggested solutions and then decide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the to be formatted like code (I assume that is what you mean) you can use the following code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{my_r_code_test.r}
R code
@
|\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}|
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed}

\lstset{
  language=R,
  backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,% basic font setting
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black!5,linewidth=0pt,%
  innerleftmargin=0pt,innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt]
\lstinputlisting[escapeinside=||]{my_r_code_test.r}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

at the top of the page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dear Heather, thank you for pointing me at the listings package. I did not use it for this problem, because some of the code blocks should also contain the output of mycode in R. At the moment, I used the functions of sweave (in R) to allow that. Is it possible to display two lstlisting blocks in two columns, i.e. next to each other?

Comment: @Llarian, I'm not sure about the two columns. Though, if you want to include the output of your code, can't you include it as an image, using the `graphicx` package? Here, let me check something real quick.

Comment: @Llarian, I updated my code to show how to include an image.

Comment: thank you, I will consider that. An advantage of using Sweave is though that all my output is calculated using my current R version, and thus considers new versions of the software I use. If I include the output as a picture, I loose this advantage. Nevertheless, it would allow me to add comments.